# Pressure measurement

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pressure

[image][image: enter image here][image]

In question 3-37,we have 
P-p(ATM)=density * g* h and we get h as 8.3 m
But the answer is 1.53 m.How and why?What is wrong in my approach?

Comment: What value did you use for the density of mecury?

Comment: The thought that a doctor's office would put on a BP cuff and then dump my vein into that apparatus is frightening, to say the least!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft only have to go back a couple of hundred years and blood-letting was a « current » treatment...

Comment: @SolarMike in your childhood, then?

Comment: I have taken it as 13600 kg/m^3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressure due to mercury is:
Pm = 13600*9.81*0.12
   = 16010

So, that is the pressure created by the blood and it will then rise:

hb = 16010/(1040*9.81)
   = 1.57m

Obviously, I have used constants I am aware of - subtle differences will give 1.53m...

Edit the density of mercury is 13560kg/m3 so that is where my error comes in...

Comment: Then please accept the answer by using the “tick” ....